# How do I find the transactions are deposited into the bank account from square

Tags: api, square

Currently, I'm using List Settlements API endpoint of Square to get the deposited transactions. But this settlement endpoint returns only the settlements. Then I need to call Retrieve settlement endpoint to get the payments associated with that particular settlement. In the response of the Retrieve endpoint, I'm getting the entries object that contains the payments and I'm getting the payment_id. Now I need to call the Retrieve payment API endpoint to get the details of the payment.

I need to get all the transactions from the settlements without making the multiple API calls. Can anyone please give me the solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to get all the transactions from a settlement without making multiple API calls.